# Unity: ошибка "NullReferenceException" при взаимодействии с объектом

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor, unity3d-ui

**Задача**: игра от 1-го лица. Управление персонажем по джойстикам, пишется под смартфон. Персонаж должен подойти к объекту, увидеть кнопки и брать / бросать объект по тапу на кнопки.

**Алгоритм**:

1. Игрок (Player) подходит к объекту, с которым нужно взаимодействовать - мяч (Ball)
2. Игрок вступает в коллайдер, дочерний мячу – активируются UI-кнопки подбора (grabButton) и броска (throwButton) мяча:

   ```
   private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
   {
       if (other.gameObject.name == "Player")
       {
           grabButton.SetActive(false);
           throwButton.SetActive(false);
       }
   }
   ```
3. При нажатии кнопки «Взять» - активируется метод «Grab»:

   ```
   public void Grab()
   {
       _rb.useGravity = false;
       _rb.isKinematic = true;
       _rb.MovePosition(_arm.position);
       _fpc.take = true;
   }
   ```
4. При нажатии кнопки «Бросить» - активируется метод «Throw»:

   ```
   public void Throw()
   {
       _rb.AddForce(Camera.main.transform.forward * 800);
       _rb.useGravity = true;
       _rb.isKinematic = false;
       _fpc.take = false;
       //_throw.throwAbility = true;
   }
   ```

**Вопрос**: при нажатии на Throw – ошибка:
`NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object ColliderGrab.Throw () (at Assets/ColliderGrab.cs:48)`

Пробовал и метод `OnClick`, и через `if (Input.Getkey)` – результат тот же. Пожалуйста, подскажите, в чём проблема. Весь скрипт висит на коллайдере-триггере, дочернем к мячу.

P.S.: я начинающий и это мой первый вопрос, сори за возможные недочёты. Заранее спасибо!

**Код целиком**:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ColliderGrab : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject grabButton;
    public GameObject throwButton;

    public Rigidbody _rb;
    private FpcParam _fpc;
    public Transform _arm;

    private void Start()
    {
        _rb = GameObject.Find("Ball").GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        _fpc = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<FpcParam>();
    }

    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.name == "Player")
        {
            grabButton.SetActive (true);
            throwButton.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.name == "Player")
        {
            grabButton.SetActive(false);
            throwButton.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    public void Grab()
    {
        _rb.useGravity = false;
        _rb.isKinematic = true;
        _rb.MovePosition(_arm.position);
        _fpc.take = true;
    }

    public void Throw()
    {
        _rb.AddForce(Camera.main.transform.forward * 800);
        _rb.useGravity = true;
        _rb.isKinematic = false;
        _fpc.take = false;
        }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (_rb.isKinematic == true)
        {
            _rb.gameObject.transform.position = _arm.position;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Когда вы обращаетесь к членам объекта через точку в то время когда сам объект `null`, возникает такое исключение. Попробуйте с помощью `Debug.Log` выяснить, что там на самом деле `null`.